# How do escape ? symbol with router.navigate in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, router

There is the navigate method:

```
this.router.navigate(['/authenticated/search/?q=' + value]);
```

I need to left the '?' symbol in url but after navigating url becomes

```
/authenticated/search/%3Fq%3D
```

How do escape '?' symbol with router.navigate in angular?

Comment: Try `this.router.navigate(['/authenticated/search/], { queryParams: { q: value } });`

Comment: If I understand correctly the https://angular.io/guide/router doc then you can do `this.router.navigate(['/authenticated/search/'],{q:value})`

Answer (score -2):

Try escaping it like this:

```js
console.log('/authenticated/search/?q='.replace('?', '\\?'));
```